# How do you get common debris?

Tags: diablo-iii

The tooltip for common debris says that you can get it from salvaging "normal" items. Does that mean "white" items? I haven't seen a single one drop since the new patch.

Since all the new recipes I've seen call for common debris, it seems pretty important to farm a lot of it if you want to craft. Where can I find it? What's the most efficient way to get it?

Comment: Sub question, what is common debris used for?

Comment: @DiabloMonkey Crafting pretty much everything.

Comment: Best place to find Common Debris - halls of anguish or whatever the grisly torture chamber areas are called in act 1 just before the butcher.

Answer (score 7):

Yes "Common Debris" are obtained from slavaging white items and you can drop it on monsters too.

I played 1-2 hours (in Torment 1) yesterday, I've looted ~30 white items and some Common Debris.

Comment: I also got some direct common debris drops.I'm pretty sure they added it later on as a drop.People would just buy white items from the vendors with some low lvl character that's why they made vendor sold items not salvageable,and since it is harder to get white items later on it seems they needed direct drops to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Paf's answer is right about how to get it - salvage white items, or count for drops from monsters. I'd like to add my suggestion for the most efficient way to get it: start a new character, or play Act I on lowest difficulty with a character with low or none magic find bonus . It seems the debris can be salvaged from *any* white item, and the most I've seen was at the start of the game.

Comment: talking about magic find: my barbarian paragon 58(was 54 or so before the patch) only has 20% MF. So it's not really necessary to start a new character to have low MF

Comment: @Novarg Agreed. That's not what I meant to say, though. I just wanted to suggest, that IF you're to start a new character, you might as well salvage all the whites you find along the way.

Comment: In addition, I've found that higher level whites/greys give more common derbris. A level 60 2-hand axe gave me ~30.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way is to make a new char (barb) over and over and scavenge the starting items.